# cargar contenido de un sitio web en C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, web, aplicación-web

amigos, tengo el siguiente problema:
estoy realizando un programa que obtiene información desde una página web, en este caso:
[direccion del trabajo](https://www.dt.gob.cl/legislacion/1624/w3-search.php?_q=rango1_pnid_2294%3D2019-11-01%26rango2_pnid_2294%3D2020-11-07)

el código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
string html = string.Empty;
            string url = URL;

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.UserAgent = "C# console client";

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                html = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            Console.WriteLine(html);
```

también probé con webClient.
Tecnicamente el programa no arroja error y me carga el contenido de la página pero sin resultados.
si lo hago por el sitio web la respuesta es distinta y me carga el listado de documentos.

necesito ayuda para poder cargar la pagina con los resultados de la búsqueda.
desde ya muchas gracias.

saludos.

Answer (score 0):

el sitio necesita una cookie para el resultado:

request.AddHeader("Cookie", "search_q" + sCookieValue + "; search_fullresult=1");